# MySQL: storing several boolean values in one column. One tinyint(4) -vs- several tinyint(4)

Tags: mysql, performance, boolean, tinyint

I need to store 5 boolean values in 1 table.
Each value could be stored as tinyint(4). So, there are 5 tinyint(4).
I'm thinking of putting 5 boolean values in one tinyint(4).
I believe, everybody knows even better than me, 5 bits could be saved in 1 byte with no problem:)
The first value could be stored as 0(false) or 1(true), the second as 0(false) or 2(true), the third as 0 or 4, fourth as 0 or 8, fifth as 0 or 16.
So, if we store the sum of that values in tinyint(4), we exactly know 5 Boolean values.

```
    For example, stored 21 -> 16 + 4+1.
So, if 21 is stored, we know that:
    Fifth=true
    Fourth=false
    Third=true
    Second=false
    First=true.
```

My question is:
Does it make sense to keep only 1 variable? We win db volume (bytes) and performance (4 columns less, but that's only 4 bytes whereas you have actually used varchar(1000) in the same table), but every time we have to "extract" a proper Boolean value from "sum" using php function, and that happens often (let's say when a user presses the button).
Does it all make sense to store Boolean values as a sum in 1 column or not, so you have 7 columns instead of 11?

That values, that's clear (because that table has much more rows that just 2), are not keys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't do this** -- unless *the value is a single "opaque" external data-type*, such as a Enum of flags -- **if the columns will *ever* be used in a query or will *ever* be used outside of said "opaque" type: use discrete/separate fields.** (Of the correct type, as jmucchiello and MarkR noted in their answers.)

Trying "for performance" here will just make you loath databases -- and this one in particular -- when you have to "fix" it or work around the ugly scheme later. (If you have a performance problem you'll know it ... *and* know enough to run a *performance analysis* before asking.) Donald Knuth was right when he pointed out that 97% of stuff Just Doesn't Matter. So make it pretty and let the database do what it feels like doing.

Happy coding.

---

If I sound animated above, it's because I'm trying help others avoid the same mistakes I've <del>done</del> run into :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make sense.

Either store each in its own column, OR use the MySQL-specific SET type, which internally uses bitfields, but is more human-readable.

Worrying about a few bytes per row is really a bad idea. It is a case of incredibly premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [BIT Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) and let MySQL worry about optimizing for space?

Comment: Regarding mysql.com, "bit(M) takes approximately (M+7)/8 bytes". (1+7)/8  is about 1 byte - the same thing as tinyint(4). What's the difference?

Comment: What's the benefit of writing complicated bit manip functions in a database application? Let the database handle storage. It's its job.

Comment: BIT type takes only 1 byte even if you have 8 BIT columns. So you cannot beat it with your custom implementation because tinyint(4) also takes 1 byte. Why not use several BIT columns instead of using tinybit?